# Is there a quick way to get the full path of a file from Finder?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Currently, I have to navigate to the file's location in shell and then copy the path. I'd love to be able to do this directly in Finder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click it then hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>

Copy [filename] will change to Copy [filename] as Pathname.

Note that pressing  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  first doesn't work, it has to be right click, then Opt.

You can also drag the file into Terminal to achieve the same thing.

Comment: WHOA! This is so cool! Thank you!!